# Moving Portable Office. Have a LAN & Phone line query?

Tags: networking, phone, local-area-network

We are about to move a portable office that has 8 phones and 12 lan connections. They are all wired back to our main switch and Nortel bcm200 phone system which are only about 20m (65ft) away. After the move the office will be 180m (600ft) away from these. What is the maximum length of cable a digital phone line can be? I am aware that a lan connection can only be 100m (305ft) when using cat5e utp. Does this rule apply to phone connections also? If so how can I extend beyond 100m for the phones? I was going to install about three cabinets, 3 switches and 6 patch panels for the lan connections but the ideal struck me tonight that maybe I could run a fibre optic line. Would this be feasible? Any feedback on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Fiber optic will likely be the way to go. However, it is not simple to terminate and requires special equipment. You'll probably have to pay someone to come out and terminate the cable for you.